# Android Studio — Render errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-emulator

Here is a screenshot of my android studio and you can see those errors at bottom messages and the render errors.

How do I fix these errors? [screeneshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxpzd.png)

Comment: you have to download the missing libs from the network. Click the `Disable...` message to do that

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says disable offline mode.

Do it by settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle->Offline Work

Answer (score 1):

Click on “disable offline mode and sync” when having an active internet connection. This will download all the necessary dependencies and resolve these errors.

Alternatively, you can remove dependencies from `build.gradle` file.
For e.g, removing the line

`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12’`

will resolve the junit error. 
I suggest you to sync the project when on an active internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your PC to internet and sync your project.

Android studio can download some content. So internet connection is required